# GoogleApiClient in helper class

Tags: android, google-api-client, android-location

I'm developing an android app, that occasionally needs to get users current location and send it to a server. I've implemented this using `GoogleApiClient` and this **[guide series](https://developer.android.com/training/building-location.html)**.

It works pretty well, but I have a bothering question. All the guides show how to request location in Activities, and none shows something like helper class, which you use anywhere by composition. Is it a bad practice? If so, why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can implement by using `interface`

Comment: This is actually what I've done. I use an abstract Activity.